# How to handle unserialize data

Tags: php

**cla** is an array that I save into the database (MySQL) using php

```
$input = serialize($_POST['cla']);

//in the database I have: 
a:3:{s:6:"t9ffj7";s:27:"Paul";s:7:"71ciz86";s:27:"Peter";s:7:"awez69g";s:27:"Marie";}
```

To get the array from the database, I unserialize it and apply the var_dump() to it.

```
<?php 
$output = var_dump(unserialize($row['li_file'])); 
echo $output; 
?>
```

then, I get  this as output:

```
array (size=3)
  't9ffj7' => string 'Paul' (length=4)
  '71ciz86' => string 'Peter' (length=5)
  'awez69g' => string 'Marie' (length=5)
```

I would like to used each key to get the corresponding value. 
so that, e.g.

```
$first_element = array['t9ffj7'];
echo $first_element; //I expect **Paul**
```

Could someone help me ?

Comment: What isn't working with this code?

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $output = unserialize($row['li_file']); 
    foreach($output as $key=>$val){
        //echo $val; or
        echo $output[$key];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try reading the question and expected output again...

Comment: Hey @nelsonrakson, I can rebuild an array with your answer, and handle it as I expect. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure @Kvin